# How to Fetch APIs and Print first element in response Array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, fetch-api

My React Native app fetch  API data and I need to print the first index of response but it's not, and gets all of the "ozone" for example in all child of the parent Array and when I print `val[0]` when Mapping  I have nothing printed

[image: the Result I need just one of them]

My Code:

```
export default class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = { isLoading: true, dataSource: null };
    }
    async componentDidMount() {
        let API_WEATHER =
              "https://api.weatherbit.io/v2.0/forecast/daily?city=Raleigh,NC&key={API_KEY}";
        fetch(API_WEATHER)
           .then(response => response.json())
           .then(responseJson => {
               console.log(responseJson.data);
               this.setState({
                 isLoading: false,
                 dataSource: responseJson.data
               });
           })
          .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
       });
    }   
  render() {
    if (this.state.isLoading) {
      return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, padding: 20 }}>
          <ActivityIndicator size="large" />
        </View>
      );
   }
  let weather= this.state.dataSource.map((val, key) => {
      return (
         <Text key={key}>
            {val.ozone}
         </Text>
      );
 });
return (
    <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
        <ScrollView>
           <View>
              <Text>{weather}</Text>
           </View>
        </ScrollView>
    </ScrollView>
   ); 
 }
```

In this part of the code when I log the response JSON obj

```
    .then(responseJson => {
            console.log(responseJson.data);
            console.log(responseJson.data[0]);
            console.log(responseJson.data[0].datetime);
}
```

I have what I need, but when print them in View I have errors:
look at the Images

[image: Console]

Comment: what is the output of ` console.log(responseJson.data);`?

Comment: @AkrionI have an Array of objects

Comment: @Akrion check the update issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably the first key of the object.

```
obj[Object.keys(obj)[0]];
```

Also, you can use

Try the for … in loop and break after the first iteration

```
for (var prop in object) {
    // object[prop]
    break;
}
```

Comment: Nope, I need to print object number  One in the Hole Response Array which contains 16 objects then print the elements of this object num 1 look at last screenShots  in Q

Comment: so you need an array of the obj keys and only after that it's possible to get the first by index

Comment: hmm,can you manipulate your code "obj[Object.keys(obj)[0]];" and put in my our Code ?

Comment: Oh, I do it  :D, Thank you, bro !

Comment: Okay man, but i have little issue can you help me in this error, Nesting of View within Text is not currently supported react native ?                                      i just put some Text having the response with Parent View